# How can I import my global state into react-testing-library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, testing, react-testing-library

My problem is when I try to import my global state for my popup into my testing file and try to use it. Then it tells me that I am using the hook wrong and it doesn't work.

my testing code:

```
import React from 'react'
import Popup from '../Popup'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
import 'mutationobserver-shim'
import { usePopupState } from '../../../constants/States'

describe('testing PopupComponent', () => {
  it('should add correctly', () => {
    const { setOpenPopup } = usePopupState()
    setOpenPopup(true)
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Popup />)
    expect(getByTestId('textfield-name')).toBeEmpty()
    expect(getByTestId('add-popup-container')).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

my global state code:

```
export interface IPopupState {
    openPopup: boolean,
    setOpenPopup:(state: boolean) => void
}

export const usePopupState = create<IPopupState>(set => ({
  openPopup: false,
  setOpenPopup: (state: boolean) => set({ openPopup: state }),
}))
```

How can I solve this problem with react-testing-library?